# mySQL cannot INSERT into one of the tables

Tags: php, mysql

I inherited this code and I can ot get it to INSERT into the first table "property_tbl"

The upload, resize and INSERT of the image part works fine.

But I am not getting any errors. And I have been staring at it for days now.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION[ss_user_id])){
    $header("Location: login.php"); 
}

include_once("includes/config.inc.php");
include_once("includes/function.inc.php");

$pro_type_id = $_REQUEST["pro_type_id"];
$pro_sid = $_REQUEST["pro_sid"];
$pro_name = $_REQUEST["pro_name"];
$pro_name_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_name_jp"];
$pro_title = $_REQUEST["pro_title"];
$pro_title_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_title_jp"];
$pro_desc = htmlentities($_REQUEST["pro_desc"],ENT_QUOTES);
$pro_desc_jp = htmlentities($_REQUEST["pro_desc_jp"],ENT_QUOTES);
$pro_notes = $_REQUEST["pro_notes"];
$pro_notes_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_notes_jp"];
$pro_address = $_REQUEST["pro_address"];
$pro_address_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_address_jp"];
$pro_email = $_REQUEST["pro_email"];
$pro_email_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_email_jp"];
$pro_contact = $_REQUEST["pro_contact"];
$pro_contact_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_contact_jp"];
$pro_price_low = $_REQUEST["pro_price_low"];
$pro_price_rent_high = $_REQUEST["pro_price_rent_high"];
$pro_price_rent_long = $_REQUEST["pro_price_rent_long"];
$pro_size_ext = $_REQUEST["pro_size_ext"];
$pro_ownership = $_REQUEST["pro_ownership"];
$pro_ownership_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_ownership_jp"];
$pro_house_stands = $_REQUEST["pro_house_stands"];
$pro_house_stands_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_house_stands_jp"];
$pro_years_left = $_REQUEST["pro_years_left"];
$pro_house = $_REQUEST["pro_house"];
$pro_house_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_house_jp"];
$pro_years_left_house = $_REQUEST["pro_years_left_house"];
$pro_common = $_REQUEST["pro_common"];
$pro_common_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_common_jp"];
$pro_price = $_REQUEST["pro_price"];
$pro_price_rent = $_REQUEST["pro_price_rent"];
$pro_price_rai = $_REQUEST["pro_price_rai"];
$size_land_rai = $_REQUEST["size_land_rai"];
$size_land_ngan = $_REQUEST["size_land_ngan"];
$size_land_wah = $_REQUEST["size_land_wah"];
$pro_bed = $_REQUEST["pro_bed"];
$pro_bath = $_REQUEST["pro_bath"];
$pro_land = $_REQUEST["pro_land"];
$pro_size = $_REQUEST["pro_size"];
$pro_view = $_REQUEST["pro_view"];
$pro_view_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_view_jp"];
$pro_furnished = $_REQUEST["pro_furnished"];
$pro_furnished_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_furnished_jp"];
$pro_furniture = $_REQUEST["pro_furniture"];
$pro_furniture_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_furniture_jp"];
$pro_kitchen = $_REQUEST["pro_kitchen"];
$pro_kitchen_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_kitchen_jp"];
$pro_internet = $_REQUEST["pro_internet"];
$pro_internet_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_internet_jp"];
$pro_aircon = $_REQUEST["pro_aircon"];
$pro_aircon_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_aircon_jp"];
$pro_pool = $_REQUEST["pro_pool"];
$pro_pool_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_pool_jp"];
$pro_parking = $_REQUEST["pro_parking"];
$pro_parking_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_parking_jp"];
$pro_distancetown = $_REQUEST["pro_distancetown"];
$pro_distancebeach = $_REQUEST["pro_distancebeach"];
$pro_features = $_REQUEST["pro_features"];
$pro_features_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_features_jp"];
$pro_loc = $_REQUEST["pro_loc"];
$pro_loc_jp = $_REQUEST["pro_loc_jp"];
$pro_status = $_REQUEST["pro_status"];
$pro_reccom = $_REQUEST["pro_reccom"];

$query = "INSERT INTO property_tbl SET
    pro_type_id = '$pro_type_id',
    pro_sid = '$pro_sid',
    pro_name = '$pro_name',
    pro_name_jp = '$pro_name_jp',
    pro_title = '$pro_title',
    pro_title_jp = '$pro_title_jp',
    pro_desc = '$pro_desc',
    pro_desc_jp = '$pro_desc_jp',
    pro_notes = '$pro_notes',
    pro_notes_jp = '$pro_notes_jp',
    pro_address = '$pro_address',
pro_address_jp = '$pro_address_jp',
pro_email = '$pro_email',
pro_email_jp = '$pro_email_jp',
pro_contact = '$pro_contact',
pro_contact_jp = '$pro_contact_jp',
pro_price_low = '$pro_price_low',
pro_price_rent_high = '$pro_price_rent_high',
pro_price_rent_long = '$pro_price_rent_long',
pro_size_ext = '$pro_size_ext',
pro_ownership = '$pro_ownership',
pro_ownership_jp = '$pro_ownership_jp',
pro_house_stands = '$pro_house_stands',
pro_house_stands_jp = '$pro_house_stands_jp',
pro_years_left = '$pro_years_left',
pro_house = '$pro_house',
pro_house_jp = '$pro_house_jp',
pro_years_left_house = '$pro_years_left_house',
pro_common = '$pro_common',
pro_common_jp = '$pro_common_jp',
    pro_price = '$pro_price',
    pro_price_rent = '$pro_price_rent',
    pro_price_rai = '$pro_price_rai',
    size_land_rai = '$size_land_rai',
    size_land_ngan = '$size_land_ngan',
    size_land_wah = '$size_land_wah',
    pro_bed = '$pro_bed',
    pro_bath = '$pro_bath',
    pro_land = '$pro_land',
    pro_size = '$pro_size',
    pro_view = '$pro_view',
    pro_view_jp = '$pro_view_jp',
    pro_furnished = '$pro_furnished',
    pro_furnished_jp = '$pro_furnished_jp',
    pro_furniture = '$pro_furniture',
    pro_furniture_jp = '$pro_furniture_jp',
    pro_kitchen = '$pro_kitchen',
    pro_kitchen_jp = '$pro_kitchen_jp',
    pro_internet = '$pro_internet',
    pro_internet_jp = '$pro_internet_jp'
    pro_aircon = '$pro_aircon',
    pro_aircon_jp = '$pro_aircon_jp',
    pro_pool = '$pro_pool',
    pro_pool_jp = '$pro_pool_jp',
    pro_parking = '$pro_parking',
    pro_parking_jp = '$pro_parking_jp',
    pro_distancetown = '$pro_distancetown',
    pro_distancebeach = '$pro_distancebeach',
    pro_features = '$pro_features',
    pro_features_jp = '$pro_features_jp',
    pro_loc = '$pro_loc',
    pro_loc_jp = '$pro_loc_jp',
    pro_status = '$pro_status',
    pro_reccom = '$pro_reccom',
    pro_adddate = '$date_now',
    pro_addby = '$_SESSION[ss_user_id]'";

mysql_query($query);
echo "<br /><br />".$query;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM property_tbl ORDER BY pro_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result  = mysql_query($sql);
$line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$NewId = $line["pro_id"]; 

foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error){
    if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
        $uploads_normal = '../images/pro-photo/normals';
        $uploads_thumb = '../images/pro-photo/thumbnails';
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $pic_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$pic_name)));
        $imgname = $nextId.md5(rand() * time()).".".$ext;
        /* resize normal photo*/
        $width1=800; 
        $size1=GetimageSize($tmp_name);
        $height1=round($width1*$size1[1]/$size1[0]);
        if($ext == "jpg" or $ext=="jpeg"){
            $images_orig1 = ImageCreateFromJPEG($tmp_name);
        }elseif($ext =="png"){
            $images_orig1 = ImageCreateFromPNG($tmp_name);
        }elseif($ext =="gif"){
            $images_orig1 = ImageCreateFromGIF($tmp_name);
        }
        $photoX1 = ImagesX($images_orig1);
        $photoY1 = ImagesY($images_orig1);

        $images_fin1 = ImageCreateTrueColor($width1, $height1);
        ImageCopyResampled($images_fin1, $images_orig1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width1+1, $height1+1, $photoX1, $photoY1);

        if ($ext == "jpg" or $ext == "jpeg"){
            ImageJPEG($images_fin1,"$uploads_normal/".$imgname);
        }elseif($ext == "png"){
            ImagePNG($images_fin1,"$uploads_normal/".$imgname);
        }elseif($ext == "gif"){
            ImageGIF($images_fin1,"$uploads_normal/".$imgname);
        }
        ImageDestroy($images_orig1);
        ImageDestroy($images_fin1);
        $width=303; 
        $size=GetimageSize($tmp_name);
        $height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
        if($ext == "jpg" or $ext=="jpeg"){
            $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($tmp_name);
        }elseif($ext =="png"){
            $images_orig = ImageCreateFromPNG($tmp_name);
        }elseif($ext =="gif"){
            $images_orig = ImageCreateFromGIF($tmp_name);
        }
        $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
        $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);

        $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
        ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
        if ($ext == "jpg" or $ext == "jpeg"){
            ImageJPEG($images_fin,"$uploads_thumb/".$imgname);
        }elseif($ext == "png"){
            ImagePNG($images_fin,"$uploads_thumb/".$imgname);
        }elseif($ext == "gif"){
            ImageGIF($images_fin,"$uploads_thumb/".$imgname);
        }
        ImageDestroy($images_orig);
        ImageDestroy($images_fin);
        $sql_img = "INSERT INTO pro_img (img_id, pro_id, img_name) VALUES ('', '$NewId', '$imgname')";
        if(mysql_query($sql_img)){
//          print "<script language='javascript'>alert('Add Property complete.');</script>";
//          print "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=index.php'>";
        }
    }
}
print "<script language='javascript'>alert('Add Property complete.');</script>";
print "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=index.php'>";
?>
```

config.inc.php is just the database connection, which works fine.

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: you don't check for errors so not seeing any is no surprise `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` and STOP using mysql_* and unsantised input

Comment: Well..staring certainly didn't help you..:P

Comment: let me guess, you never made it to this: `echo "<br /><br />".$query;` ?

Comment: `'` or `"` chars can cause many syntax error. Don't trust data which comes from user with POST, GET etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would echo the query and try it in sequel pro, you probably have misspelt some table names.
Also I would never type all this code, instead foreach over $REQUEST and append it to the query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO property_tbl SET";
foreach($REQUEST as $key => $value) {
    $query .= $key . "= '". $value."',";
}
```

and delete the comma after the loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your ideas. But it turns out that staring at it did work eventually.

The problem was a missing comma after $pro_internet_jp

```
pro_internet = '$pro_internet',
pro_internet_jp = '$pro_internet_jp'
pro_aircon = '$pro_aircon',
```

All working fine now.

Thanks